# Best Design For Constantly Changing Property Within A Singleton Class With IoC Usage?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inversion-of-control, unity-container, property-injection

I have the following helper class which has public property _variableHandler. The property is public as I initially had visions of setting the property from the calling code before involving methods within the XAMLHelper class, but now doubt this is a smart approach. Mostly because I will need to call the class fairly often and not always update the value of _variableHandler, meaning things will get messy.

```
public class XAMLHelper
{
    public IVariableTypeHandler _variableHandler;

    public XAMLHelper()
    {
    }
}
```

I also have a factory which is used to provide the desired concrete instance of a VariableTypeHandler.

I am also using an IoC container (Unity) to provide a single instance of the XAMLHelper class, as shown below.

```
container.RegisterInstance<XAMLHelper>(new XAMLHelper());
```

Ideally, I would like to keep this single instance but simply update the value of _variableHandler when specified using like the code below.

```
container.Resolve(new PropertyInjection(VariableHandlerFactory.GetInstance("Str")));
```

I have tried adding snippets into container registration, such as a

```
new InjectionProperty()
```

But this doesn't seem to update the _variableHandler property once it has been instantiated the first time. Am I missing something important here? Or trying to do something that is not possible with an IoC container?

Comment: Does `VariableHandlerFactory.GetInstance("Str")` return the instance of the `IVariableTypeHandler`? Also I think you need to annotate property with `[Dependency]` attribute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, good design proposes making *helper\manipulator\operation* classes stateless. Here you clearly have a helper class which is stateful as you are able to set the state of the object through the property `_variableHandler` (not real property, it is more like a field).

What you could do is to make factory for `IVariableHandler` register that within the IoC and inject it into `XAMLHelper`. Then when invoking helper you just specify which handler to use and re-create it with factory. Factory could be a bit smarter to reuse already create object using some kind of caching.

```
public intefrace IVariableHandlerFactory
{
    IVariableHandler Get(string description);
}

public class VariableHandlerFactory : IVariableHandlerFactory
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, IVariableHandler> _cache;

    public VariableHandlerFactory()
    {
        _cache = new Dictionary<string, IVariableHandler>();
    }

    public IVariableHandler Get(string description)
    {
        IVariableHandler handler; 

        if(_cache.TryGetValue(description, out handler))
        {
            return handler;         
        }

        handler = //create it...
        _cache[description] = handler;

        return handler;
    }
}
```

and then use that within `XAMLHelper`

```
public class XAMLHelper
{
    private readonly IVariableHandlerFactory _factory;

    public XAMLHelper(IVariableHandlerFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void HelpMe(string description)
    {
        var handler = _factory.Get(description);

        //do actual work using handler
    }
}
```

---

Let's put that aside, and discuss the real problem here. First, you are missing annotation of your property:

```
[Dependency]
public IVariableTypeHandler VariableHandler { get; set; }
```

then you could register the `XAMLHelper` using the `InjectionProperty`

```
container.RegisterType<VariableTypeHandlerImpl, IVariableTypeHandler>();

using(var lifetime = new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
    container.RegisterType<XAMLHelper>(lifetime, new InjectionProperty("VariableHandler");
```

or, if you have concrete instance of the `IVariableTypeHandler` you could use:

```
var variableHandler = VariableHandlerFactory.GetInstance("Str");

using(var lifetime = new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
    container.RegisterType<XAMLHelper>(lifetime, new InjectionProperty("VariableHandler", variableHandler);
```

Comment: Indeed, `VariableHandlerFactory.GetInstance("Str")` does return an instance of `IVariableTypeHandler`. Can you suggest a simple way to make the `XAMLHelper` class stateless but still use the VariableHandlers produced by the factory? I have also added the 'Dependency' attribute as suggested and then used this code `container.Resolve<XAMLHelper>(new PropertyOverride("VariableHandler", VariableHandlerFactory.GetInstance("Int")));` to update the property from the default VariableHandler (as dictated in the container registration), but it does not seem to update the property. Any suggestions?

Comment: @unknownpresense For example, why `XAMLHelper` have to be singleton, could you create it every time and inject `IVariableTypeHandler`? How many variation do of `IVariableTypeHandler`, could you register all types of it?

Comment: The `XAMLHelper` class is called around 100 times per cycle and the process can cycle up to 30 times in a run. The `VariableHandler` property is updated roughly 6 times within those 100 calls. I figured making a new instance every time would be a bit overkill. There are currently 20 variations of `IVariableHandler` but that could easily grow to double that, which is why I decided a factory would be appropriate. I am trying to code to a high standard (following SOLID, DRY etc) so any improvements would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: @unknownpresense For `IVariableHandler` you could have factory or builder that is fine, maybe factory with underlaying cache so you create only once and store if it is possible. Then inject that factory in `XAMLHelper` and invoke methods on XAMLHelper by specifying which `IVariableHandler` to use... Is that possible?

Comment: That is a great idea! A bonus question here is how would I cache the previously created `IVariableHandler`'s? I considered making them all singletons, could this work? Also I believe your suggestion of specifying which handler to use will solve my problem! I can then simply check the current handler on `XAMLHelper` is the same as the specified one and update if not :D

Comment: @unknownpresense You can cache them as simple as `IDictionary<Type, IVariableHandler>`. The one in `XAMLHelper` is not really needed but could be also like L1, L2 caches... Should I wrap this also in the answer?

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, that would help me massively! Thank you, appreciate the help :)